# Selecting a distinct column with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to select just 1 distinct column to determine the records that are shown in my query. The column userid is capable of owning several houses which mean userid can be present multiple times currently. However, I only care if they own one house, so I'd like the userid column to be distinct, while the rest of the rows can remain to be whatever is within that row.

```
Select UserID, House, NumOfPpl, NumOfCars 
from people
```

Results:

```
userID  House  NumOfPpl  NumOfCars 
-----------------------------------
1a        red    3          2
1a        blue   1          1
2a        red    3          3
3a        green  4          6
3ab       red    2          1
3ab       blue   2          1
```

Would need to be:

```
userID  House  NumOfPpl  NumOfCars
----------------------------------
1a        red    3          2
2a        red    3          3
3a        green  4          6
3ab       red    2          1
```

It looks like when I try to do a count on userID, I get a value of '1' for each row as it is counting the house aswell.

```
Select UserID, count(UserId), House, NumOfPpl, NumOfCars 
from people 
group by UserID, House, NumOfPpl, NumOfCars
```

Comment: If you don't care about the rest of the data simply SELECT DISTINCT userId FROM people.  If you want a count:  SELECT userId, COUNT(userId) FROM people GROUP BY userId.  Selecting distinct with multiple columns will get you unique combinations of the columns.

Comment: Is there are primary key for this table?  No primary key means not First Normal Form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must have all columns, select the first record from each partition by userid

```
 ;with cte AS (
    select userid, 
    house, 
    numofppl, 
    numofcars, 
    row_number() OVER(partition by userID order by house) AS rowcounter
    FROM people
)

SELECT userid, house, numofppl, numofcars
from cte 
WHERE rowcounter = 1
```